Multiple conditions within a single if statement
I want to know if I can assign different variables for different conditions embedded in a single if statement. (I am sorry if my terminology is incorrect, please correct me wherever! much appreciated!)
if p==r or p==t or p==y:
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    z=z+1

so here my query:
I've given multiple conditions within a single if statement to check from three valid answers (else condition would be for an invalid p input)
but I want to assign a different value for each outcome.
for example I want to assign p=1 if the p==r condition is true, and p=2 if the p==t condition is true without having to also put the print statement thrice.
can i do so in a single if statement?? or do i HAVE to write different statements for each one?
thank you for your answer!

If you have three different outcomes, then you should probably have three clauses.  You COULD do if p in (r,t,y): / p = [r,t,y].index(p), but clever is not always better...

In practice, you’d write some different algorithm which wouldn’t necessitate this awkward manual check against three different values to begin with, making this question moot. A more complete real world task would help illustrate such a solution, but with the minimal sample you give, there aren’t that many alternatives to suggest.

if p := {r: 1, t: 2, y: 3}.get(p): ?

You can try Python's match case statement for that or any()... Or still do as you do.

There's many ways to do what you want:

Just use elifs. The simplicity and straight-forwardness of this approach is worth more than the lines of code you could possibly reduce by using other methods. Here's the code:

if p == r: 
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    p = value1
elif p == t:
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    p = value2
elif p == y:
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    p = value3
else:
    raise ValueError('invalid value')

If you don't want to repeat the print(), then put the print() outside of the if-blocks, like this:
if p == r: 
    p = value1
elif p == t:
    p = value2
elif p == y:
    p = value3
else:
    raise ValueError('invalid value')
print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)') # won't run if value is invalid, because a ValueError will be raised.


If you don't want to raise an exception, then you can also do this:

accepted = [r, t, y]
if p in accepted:
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    if p == r: 
        p = value1
    elif p == t:
        p = value2
    elif p == y:
        p = value3
else:
    print('invalid value')


To make the code shorter, use dictionaries:

mapper = {r: value1, t: value2, y: value3}
if p in mapper:
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    p = mapper[p]
else:
    print('invalid value')


To make the code even shorter, still use dictionaries but with .get() method:

n = {r: value1, t: value2, y: value3}.get(p)
if n:
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    p = n
else:
    print("invalid value')

You can also further reduce by one line using assignment expressions:
if n := {r: value1, t: value2, y: value3}.get(p):
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
    p = n
else:
    print("invalid value')


Finally, you can use the match/case statement:

match p:
    case 1:
        p = value1
    case 2:
        p = value2
    case 3:
        p = value3
    case _:
        print('invalid value')

Note that with match/case you must hard-code the values in your case clauses.


p = 1
r,t,y=3,1,4
p = 2 if p==r else 3 if p==t else 4 if p==y else None


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

I hope this will fix you problem.
if p == r or p == t or p == y:
    if p == r:
        p = 1
    elif p == t:
        p = 2
    elif p == y:
        p = 3
    print('Great, but the computer is now choosing their COUTER ATTACK! al the best >:)')
else:
    print('Invalid input')


@Safuvan Why are you duplicating the comparisons?

@SIGHUP to assign value to p based on comparison

For example:- if p is equal to r you test it twice. Why?
